# OS agnostic path in Hydra configurations

Tags: python, hydra-core

Suppose to have the following field in a hydra config

```
  my_path: path/to/something
```

I would like this path to both work on DOS- and Unix-based OS. In Python, I would have expressed it with `os.path.join`. Is it OS agnostic by default, or should I express it with a specific syntax?